# Enable a tab with jQuery Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I disabled the tab like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ disabled: [1, 2] });
```

But when I try to enable one of the tabs it is not working:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ enabled: [1] });
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this for the jQuery UI tabs?

Comment: Try `$('#tabs').tabs('enable', 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$("selector").tabs("enable", n);` where n is the index of the tab

Comment: To enable more than one tab at once reset the disabled property like:
`$('#example').tabs("option","disabled",[]);`.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#methods

Answer (score 3):

Never used jQuery Tabs but I can't see any [option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) for `enabled`.

Have you tried to just update the list of disabled tabs to remove tab 1 ?

```
$("#tabs").tabs({ disabled: [2] });
```

or

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "enable" , 1 );
```

(that's [in the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-enable))

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for the `.tabs( "option" , optionName , [value] )` method found on this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ (click the "Method" tab and find "option" below).

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option" , "disabled" , [2] );
```

### Update

Under the section of the docs for `$(selector).tabs('enable', n)` there is this statement:

> To enable more than one tab at once reset the disabled property like:
>   `$('#example').tabs("option","disabled",[]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `$("#tabs").tabs("enable", [1])`?

Comment: I don't know if this works as well but the docs state that you pass in an index, not an array, when using `$(selector).tabs("enable", n)`